# How can I mask the first 4 digits of a stringed number

Tags: java

I want to mask the first 4 digits of a stringed number, for example, 1234567 would look like ****567

Comment: Does your string contain only number? Also what is the *hard part*? What stops you from writing code for this?

Comment: This is a pretty basic task. Have you tried actually writing some code to do this?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, it only contains numbers.

Comment: What if you instead add the last three numbers to a string consisting of four *?

Comment: Is your number always seven digits?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substring function. Try something like that

```
 String number=1234567;
 String maskNumber="****"+number.substring(4);
```

Comment: Index should be 3 not 4.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
"12345654".replaceFirst("[0-9]{4}", "****");
```

Comment: If you are going to use `replaceFirst` then you don't need `^`.

Answer (score 1):

You could to this:

```
String str = "1234567";
String firstFourChars = str.substring(0, 4);
String newStr = str.replaceFirst(firstFourChars, "****");
```

Or to make it shorter:

```
str = str.replaceFirst(str.substring(0, 4), "****");
```

Comment: What if number is `12341234`?